# Cannot prevent animateClick() from firing a signal with QPushButton.blockSignals(True)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

**Note:**
I'm working in PyQt5 on Python 3.6. But if your answer is for Qt5 in C++, that's also fine. I can translate from C++ to Python most of the time.

### 1. The problem

Sometimes I want to programmatically click a button. I like the nice animation created by `animateClick()`, but the button shouldn't fire a signal. So what I try is this:

```
    self.__myBtn.blockSignals(True)
    self.__myBtn.animateClick()
    self.__myBtn.blockSignals(False)
```

Unfortunately, the `clicked` signal fires anyway.

### 2. Demo app

I've written a standalone demo application for your convenience. It can be helpful to run some tests. Just copy-paste the code below in a python file and run it. You should see a window like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


'''================================================================================'''
'''|                           CUSTOM MAIN WINDOW                                 |'''
'''================================================================================'''
class CustomMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomMainWindow, self).__init__()

        # -------------------------------- #
        #           Window setup           #
        # -------------------------------- #

        # 1. Define the geometry of the main window
        # ------------------------------------------
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QPushbutton animateClick() test")

        # 2. Create frame and layout
        # ---------------------------
        self.__frm = QFrame(self)
        self.__frm.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: #ffffff }")
        self.__lyt = QVBoxLayout()
        self.__lyt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.__frm.setLayout(self.__lyt)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__frm)

        # 3. Create QLineEdit
        # -------------------
        self.__myBtn = QPushButton("click me")
        self.__myBtn.clicked.connect(self.__btn_clicked)
        self.__myBtn.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.__myBtn.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.__lyt.addWidget(self.__myBtn)

        for i in range(10):
            QTimer.singleShot(100 + 500*i, self.__my_click_animation)

        self.show()

    ''''''

    def __my_click_animation(self):
        self.__myBtn.blockSignals(True)
        self.__myBtn.animateClick()
        self.__myBtn.blockSignals(False)

    ''''''


    def __btn_clicked(self):
        print("I'm clicked")

'''=== end Class ==='''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    myGUI = CustomMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

''''''
```

### 3. Output of the Demo app

As soon as the main window spawns, the Demo app will run the function `self.__my_click_animation()` 10 times, with 500ms between each run:

```
    def __my_click_animation(self):
        self.__myBtn.blockSignals(True)
        self.__myBtn.animateClick()
        self.__myBtn.blockSignals(False)
```

I would expect to see the button getting clicked 10 times (the visual animation), but no signals fired. Unfortunately, the signals do fire, and I get 10 times `"I'm clicked"` printed out in my terminal.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the visual effect then you can use the `setDown()` method with a `QTimer`:

```
def __my_click_animation(self):
    self.__myBtn.setDown(True)
    QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: self.__myBtn.setDown(False))
```

Comment: Hello there. How was your coffee?

Comment: I'm sure you like some more coffee. I've sent another 3$ ;-)